# ELK: how to ignore conflict field types?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

The application make log files in json (regular Symfony json log handler), and these log files are indexed with logstash.

Log lines have timestamp, message and context.
And this context contains payload of any type, that was passed to logger in the applicaton.
And sometimes it has values with same names and different types. It can be `"context":{"type": 121}` or `"context":{"type": "text/html"}` or `"context": [1, 2, "text"]`.

Logstash doesn't add documents to index in case of different types. And Kibana doesn't show logs from different indices in case of different type in them.

How can it be solved?

Comment: Do the conflicting fields in context have simple types or complex types? Can you post example docs?

Comment: @sramalingam24 I added examples

Comment: Have you considered using the mutate plugin to turn it into a string array or something you want it to be https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html

Comment: Tht's not a good solution: I can't use filters for serialized data. But I think this problem doesn't have a solution.